# salvaging DC motors from home appliances

Tags: electrical, appliances, electric-motor

In what home appliances I can find a 40V (or so) DC motor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably none. most products that require motors will use AC motors controlled by mechanical timers (which usually use the frequency of the AC line to "tick") or small DC circuits with relays or TRIACs to switch the AC current.

as the size of the motor increases, AC motors are better than DC motors in terms of ease of construction, ease of control and power efficiency. plus, using a DC motor requires converting the AC to DC, and doing so at the higher currents a motor requires significantly increases the cost of the power supply.

so besides small motors for fans, you're likely to never see a DC motor.

Comment: o.k. but i'm sure there is something that uses 40V DC motors, no? for example, i found a 24V DC in a electric scooter (for children, as is). so in what thingi i could find a 40V motor?

Comment: probably none. common voltages for DC motors will be 12v and 24v, because that is a common voltage for batteries. what do you need a 40v battery for?

Comment: for a wind turbine. i have a charge controller that uses 35-40V in the input to play with when outputing to the battery 26-28.5V (the battery is 24V).

Comment: The scooter uses a DC motor because it runs on batteries. It's more efficient than converting battery DC to AC and then powering the motor. Anything that plugs in is going to just use AC (it's more efficient, and doesn't need the expensive power supply).

Comment: i think you have a fundamental misconception about motor vs. generator. yes, if you turn a DC motor, it will generate electricity. however, just because a DC motor is rated for 40 V doesn't mean that turning it at any speed will result in a 40 V output. instead, the output voltage will be proportional to the speed. if you want to generate electricity from the wind, what you instead is a battery charger designed for a variable current/voltage.

Answer (score 2):

Treadmills and stairlifts use good-sized DC motors.